# SQL script for merging two tables and turning rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tools` (
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
  `pk_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feature` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tools(id));
```

Then I have the script (see below) to obtain something like this:

```
Tools  Feature1 Feature2 Feature3 Feature4
=========================================
ToolA  1        0        0        1
ToolB  0        0        1        0
```

The script works fine when I put `1` instead of `number` in the line `MAX(IF(pa1.feature = "', feature,'", "', number, '", "', 0, '"))`. Otherwise it says there is some error at this line. Why and how to fix it?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(pa1.feature = "', feature,'", "', number, '", "', 0, '")) AS ', REPLACE(feature, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM features;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id
                    , p.title
                    , ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tools p
                   LEFT JOIN features AS pa1 
                    ON p.id = pa1.id
                   GROUP BY p.id');

SELECT concat('SQL: ', @sql);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the original SQL statement that was created by the above script and that contains some error:

> SELECT p.id\n                    , p.title\n                    , MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 68\", \"6\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature68,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 68\", \"7\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature68,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 68\", \"1\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature68,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 172\", \"2\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature172,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 56\", \"1\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature56,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 193\", \"4\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature193,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 71\", \"3\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature71,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 201\", \"2\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature201,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 80\", \"2\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature80,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 203\", \"5\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature203,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 82\", \"8\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature82,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 80\", \"9\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature80,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 82\", \"9\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature82,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 201\", \"5\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature201,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 80\", \"15\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature80,MAX(IF(pa1.feature = \"feature 56\", \"3\", \"0\")) AS
>   feature56,MAX(I \n                   FROM tools p\n
>   LEFT JOIN features AS pa1 \n                    ON p.id = pa1.id\n
>   GROUP BY p.id

As I said the same code works if I substitute `number` by `1`.

Comment: When you are getting an error and want someone to fix it you really should show the error message.

Comment: @Hogan: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tools p                    LEFT JOIN feature AS pa1                     ' at line 4

Comment: You should debug this by having a print statement to see the value @sql so we know what you are actually trying to execute.

Comment: @Hogan: I posted the update with the printed statement.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your posted code.

- In sql strings are usually specified using single quotes not double quotes.  I'm not 100% with mysql so that platform might allow the code you have here.
- look at the last field `MAX(I \n FROM tools`  This is clearly wrong.

This is probably one of two things.  `@SQL` is to small or you have a null in the number column.  If the problem is you have a null then this will fix would be to use this where in your select statement.

```
FROM features
WHERE number is not null;
```

Comment: It shows the error "syntax error, unexpected varchar" at the "varchar"

Comment: I have no idea why 1 works fine, I'm not even sure what your original error was.

Comment: I checked your solutions. Also I tried SELECT * FROM features WHERE number IS NULL, but it returned an empty set. But there is definitely something wrong with number, because everything works when I take the same script and write CAST(2 AS CHAR(10) instead of CAST(number AS CHAR(10). In fact number has values 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Regarding MAX(I \n FROM tools, that's because the real statement is very long. I assume that an editor cutted out some part of the statement. I get the same MAX(I \n FROM tools for 1 or 2 instead of number, and it works without number.

Comment: You assume wrong.  I'm done wasting my time with you.

Comment: The problem was caused by the maximum number of unique features.